# Problem solution hint about boundary of boundary of chains from Arnold' book mathematical method

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

On his book Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics, (Chapter 7, Section 35, Problem 10), Arnold asks to show that the boundary of boundary of any chain is zero. He gives hint saying: by the linearity of the boundary operator it is enough to show it for a polyhedron in k dimensional space. It remain to verify that every k-2 dimensional face appear twice in the boundary of boundary with opposite sign. It is enough to prove this for k=2. I can not see why it is enough to prove this for k=2. How to generalize the proof in higher dimensions? Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Consider (1)...The boundary operator commutes with affine maps and (2)...The projection operator of k-space onto the (x,y) plane is affine. The assertion can be proved by contradiction once you have proved that (3)...the boundary of the boundary of any 2-D chain is zero. Indeed, if the boundary of the boundary of a k-D polyhedron was not zero then the projection of this would not be zero. But because the boundary operator commutes with projection this would contradict (3) since the projection of a k-D polyhedron is a 2-D chain and the projection of the boundary of the boundary of the k-D polyhedron is the boundary of the boundary of its 2-D projected image chain which is zero by (3).

Comment: "...then the projection of this would not be zero." Should this be: "then _some_ projection of this would not be zero"? Certainly you should be able to have nonzero things become zero after projection.